# Execute gradle task on sub projects

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, multi-module

I have a MultiModule gradle project that I am trying to configure.

```
Root
    projA
    projB
    other
        projC
        projD
        projE
        ...
```

What I want to be able to do is have a task in the root build.gradle which will execute the buildJar task in each of the projects in the other directory.

I know I can do

```
configure(subprojects.findAll {it.name != 'tropicalFish'}) {
    task hello << { task -> println "$task.project.name"}
}
```

But this will also get projA and projB,  I want to only run the task on c,d,e...
Please let me know the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Not entirely sure which of these you're after, but they should cover your bases.

**1. Calling the tasks directly**

You should just be able to call

```
gradle :other/projC:hello :other/projD:hello
```

I tested this with:

```
# Root/build.gradle
allprojects {
    task hello << { task -> println "$task.project.name" }
}
```

and

```
# Root/settings.gradle
include 'projA'
include 'projB'
include 'other/projC'
include 'other/projD'
```

**2. Only creating tasks in the sub projects**

Or is it that you only want the task created on the other/* projects?

If the latter, then the following works:

```
# Root/build.gradle
allprojects {
    if (project.name.startsWith("other/")) {
        task hello << { task -> println "$task.project.name" }
    }
}
```

and it can then be called with:

```
$ gradle hello
:other/projC:hello
other/projC
:other/projD:hello
other/projD
```

**3. Creating a task that runs tasks in the subprojects only**

This version matches my reading of your question meaning there's already a task on the subprojects (buildJar), and creating a task in root that will only call the subprojects other/*:buildJar

```
allprojects {
    task buildJar << { task -> println "$task.project.name" }
    if (project.name.startsWith("other/")) {
        task runBuildJar(dependsOn: buildJar) {}
    }
}
```

This creates a task "buildJar" on every project, and "runBuildJar" on the other/* projects only, so you can call:

```
$ gradle runBuildJar
:other/projC:buildJar
other/projC
:other/projC:runBuildJar
:other/projD:buildJar
other/projD
:other/projD:runBuildJar
```

Your question can be read many ways, hope this covers them all :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. None of the options suited my needs: 1. We need to know the list of all subprojects. 2+3. Build script needs to be modified. Finally, I found another way to achieve this and added it as a new answer.

Comment: @Marwin: Where is your answer? Would be interested.

Comment: @frhd See the answer below mine `gradle -p other hello`

Answer (score 63):

All of the ways [mentioned by Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26512462/306047) can be used but all of them have some cons. So I am adding one more option:

**4. Switching the current project**

```
gradle -p other hello
```

This switches the "current project" and then runs all tasks named `hello` under the current project.

Comment: Needs to be noted that this literally switches the working directory to 'other'. Therefor, this fails when there's no 'other/build.gradle' file (we use "subprojects {...}" from the parent directory to configure the child projects). That's why I recommend the other answer and the use of "gradle:taskName" instead.

Answer (score 2):

Example 5. Defining common behavior of all projects and subprojects,

```
allprojects {
    task hello {
        doLast { task ->
            println "I'm $task.project.name"
        }
    }
}
subprojects {
    hello {
        doLast {
            println "- I depend on water"
        }
    }
}
```

From the Gradle documentation,
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html