# How to use Gradle with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I've used Eclipse's install software ability with the following link (http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/gradle ) to allow use of Gradle. This works for a time, but whenever I reopen Eclipse the software is always uninstalled. Does anyone know how I can permanently install Gradle IDE for Eclipse 4.3?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use this instead https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse-44?

Also, I was in gradle summit last week and Eclipse 4.5 will be out soon and they will have built-in support for Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

See my following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30779029/4235836) to a other SO post. It gives a link to the GitHub page of the plugin where you can find how to install it. Also the post describes how to use the plugin (which may be of less interest to you).